# Cannot load 32 bit dylib from 64 bit process and vice versa on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, dylib

I came across a problem yesterday where my program failed as 32 bit process.

I had a dylib compiled as 64 bit and I was using it on 64 bit application. But when I turned it to 32 bit for testing and tried to load it, it did not worked. dlopen() returned NULL?

Do I need to have 32 bit and 64 bit dylib for 32 bit and 64 bit binary respectively? Is there any work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need 32bit libs for 32bit processes, and 64bit libs for 64bit processes. There is no workaround.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is the "workaround" of spawning a 32-bit process to mediate calls into the library via some form of IPC, but I wouldn't do that unless it was really **absolutely** necessary.

Comment: There's a better "workaround": build all libraries as fat (multiarchitecture) binaries, so they can be used from both 32- and 64-bit processes.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can build 32-bit binaries with a 64-bit compiler, and vice
   versa.
2. You can build and run 64-bit binaries when booted on a
       32-bit kernel, and vice versa.
3. You can't link 32-bit builds
       against 64-bit binaries or vice versa.

Comment: Point 2 is wrong. You can't generally run 64 code on a 32bit OS (without counting virtualization things) on x86.

Comment: Point 2 is correct for OS X -- it can run 64-bit processes under a 32-bit kernel just fine.  In fact, it's been able to since version 10.4 even though it didn't include a 64-bit kernel until 10.6 (and didn't generally use the 64-bit kernel until 10.7).